# Recieving build error when creating an alert in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I don't know if these are from SwiftUI being so new that i'm doing something wrong. I am only importing SwiftUI.

[Tryng to declare an alert in SwiftUI but keeps giving me error on build.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KVFm.png)

[All the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBbrw.png)

[I am getting the option for a UIAlertController, not the standard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHTnM.png)

Comment: Don't post the images of code instead paste code directly. Welcome to stakeoverflow, @Luke Kasson..!!

Comment: Thank you for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

if you have a primaryButton you need to provide a secondaryButton. This code here works and should answer your question:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@State var showsAlert = false
@State var errorMsg = "xxxx"

var body: some View {
    Button(action: { self.showsAlert = true }) {
        Text("press to test").padding(10).border(Color.black)
    }.alert(isPresented: self.$showsAlert) {
        Alert(title: Text(self.errorMsg),
              message: Text("text message"),
              primaryButton: Alert.Button.default(Text("yes"), action: {
                print("---> yes")
              }),
              secondaryButton: Alert.Button.default(Text("no"), action: {
                print("---> no")
        }))
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I don't even get the option for primary button or secondary button when typing 'Alert('.

Comment: so if you copy and paste this code it doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it wasn't recognizing a SwiftUI Alert and only a UIAlertContrller. Had to declare SwiftUI.Alert() and this worked.

```
.alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
                   SwiftUI.Alert(title: Text("Hello"), message: Text("Good bye"), dismissButton: .cancel({
                       print("Canclel tapped")
                   }))
               }
```

Comment: something is not right here, you should not have to do that. Did you import SwiftUI? Could you show us the full code that you use, so we can track down the issue.

Comment: No matter what the view is, empty, just a button, etc. it gives the same errors. I only have SwiftUI imported.